# How to convert List List Map to List Map

Tags: scala

I'm having trouble on conversion par

I have the Data like this

```
List(List(Map(a -> m), Map(c -> n)), List(Map(d -> o), Map(e -> p)))
```

And I wanted to have the result like this in the best way (I have done the long long way)

```
List(Map(a -> m), Map(c -> n), Map(d -> o), Map(e -> p))
```

Please any one help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calling method `flatten` should get you that.

```
scala> List(List(Map('a' -> 'm'), Map('c' -> 'n')), List(Map('d' -> 'o'), Map('e' -> 'p'))).flatten
res2: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Char]] = List(Map(a -> m), Map(c -> n), Map(d -> o), Map(e -> p))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @Muhunthan Thanks!!